# Why Are There Holes In My Mesh When I Move Vertices Using Subsurface Modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, vertices, subdivision-surface

I'm modelling a character in Edit Mode but after applying the Subdivision Surface Modifier to it, I noticed that there were a few vertices on the arm that, when moved, would create a hole.Like they are not even join to the the mesh or something. I don't know why this is. I can't leave the mesh as is because it's creating a very sharp edge and is causing problems with the shading. Don't know what is causing this or how to fix it.I just need the vertices to behave like normal. Please help!

[image: Holes created by moving one of the vertices.]

Comment: hello could you please share this part of your mesh? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: i don't think that these are holes and i think they are caused by subdivision modifier. If you turn it off, they are gone, right? you can e.g. click the left most button (with the triangle and the 3 squares) in subdiv modifier to "see all"